# How to debug a PowerPC Microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, debugging, freescale, powerpc

I want to know if it is possible to debug a powerPc MPC555 microcontroller on the device while its running with the binary not the source code. If it is possible then please tell me how to do it using BDM and what debugger and software should I use Thank you

Comment: This might be on topic in "reverse engineering" but it will need lots more detail.

Comment: Which powerPC? Does it have a JTAG COP port? If yes, you can probably use a JTAG emulator. They are expensive, so if you aren't part of a company that can buy it, you probably can't afford one.

Comment: Its a MPC555 microcontroller which have BDM.I have some debug tools that can read the binary but i want to debug it to find out a piece of code in the binary

Comment: There are some resources to do debugging over BDM using GDB and DDD. I haven't worked with that for decades but IIRC it is possible.